# How to clear sessionstorage item when user logout?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

In my controller, how do i clear the sessionStorage item?

```
public function logout(){
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
        return redirect('/login');
}
```

I stored some data inside session storage and i want to clear it after user logout. But it will only clear if the browser closed.

Answer (score 1):

To clear sessionStorage programmatically, call `sessionStorage.clear();`

Comment: i know right. But i need to clear only when user logout, but not when page refresh.

Comment: sessionStorage persists through page refreshes. Typically you would store the logged in user in sessionStorage, and in your page constructor check to see if there's a user in sessionStorage, and if so - restore that user as there's likely just been a page refresh. If there's not, it's a new load and you log in a user. When you logout, you clear sessionStorage, and if the brewer window closes (not refreshes), the sessionStorage is discarded.